# Publishing Slather Report to SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, fastlane, slather

I am using Fastlane for building and testing my ObjC project. I use **scan** action to run Unit Test cases and **slather** action to generate Code coverage report. 
I am able to generate cobertura.xml report using slather action, but unable to publish the report to SonarQube.

I am using SonarQube 6.4 and fastlane 2.64.0.

**FastFile**

```
scan(
workspace: "Sample.xcworkspace",
scheme: "SampleTests",
code_coverage: true,
output_types: "html"
)
slather(
cobertura_xml: true,
output_directory: "./reports",
proj: "Sample.xcodeproj",
workspace: "Sample.xcworkspace",
scheme: "SampleTests",
)
sonar
```

Analysis is published to Sonar but Code Coverage report is not updated. Please let me know where i miss the key.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the SonarQube log?

Comment: No. There are no logs generated in SonarQube. Is there any fields to be added in sonar-project.properties for publishing the code coverage report to SonarQube

Answer (score 1):

From your comments on your question, it seems that you haven't tried configuring the path to the report, so it's natural that no coverage data is imported. The analysis cannot intuit where reports are or that it should read them.

Having said that, you also indicate that you're generating a `cobertura.xml` file, but that's not one of the formats [currently supported by SonarCFamily for Objective-C](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCFamily+Coverage+Results+Import). So you'll need to get your coverage data into the [Generic Coverage format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data), and then include the path to that report using the `sonar.coverageReportPaths` analysis property.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. Since cobertura is not supported by SonarQube, i replaced it with gcovr in fastlane. But the report generated with gcovr is 0% Code coverage.
Code in fastlane
gcovr(
   html: true,
   html_details: true,
     output: "./code-coverage/report.html"
)

Comment: Follow the site:  https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/coverage/ and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/swift-coverage I get the error when run bash xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh Build/Logs/Test/*.xcresult/*_Test/*.xccovarchive/ > sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml 
 Error Domain=DVTCommandLineParserErrorDomain Code=3 "invalid option '--archive'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=invalid option '--archive'}